# how to switch between views in ios sdk

Tags: xcode, ios4

how can i make a button that take to another view in easy way ???

Answer (score -1):

i am not using my mac nw..so pls dnt mind the syntax

[button_name addTarget:@selector(somefunction)];
-(void)somefunction
{
 create the view newView
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:newView];
}